# Adjusting jQuery to work on Wordpress (syntaxerror)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, syntax-error

I have a line of code that has a "$" value in it, which Wordpress doesn't seem to accept. How to adjust the "$", so that Wordpress will read it correctly?

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render',function(){
    jQuery('#input_24_4').change(function(){
        jQuery('#input_24_3').data('amount',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Change `$(this).val()` to `jQuery(this).val()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` should be an alias of `jQuery`, anyway, for some reason `$` is *not defined* sometimes. You can fix it by using an anonymous function:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).bind('gform_post_render',function() {
        $('#input_24_4').change(function(){
            $('#input_24_3').data('amount',$(this).val());
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, make sure you've loaded jQuery library before embedding / executing this piece of code.

Comment: That did it, thanks! And I did have to load jQuery before executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this line of code? If it's part of a double-quoted string in any of your PHP files, you need to escape the `$` with a backslash: `\$`

Apart from that, [jQuery runs in `noConflict` mode in Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-1473). That means, it doesn't set the global `$` variable, just the `jQuery` name.

If you want to change that, you need to set it yourself somewhere before this line:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery;
```